# How to add custom property programatically in mxGraph?

Tags: mxgraph

Okay, I've a custom side-bar group as well as a right side pane with some drop-downs. This works well i.e. user can add the shape on the editor and select the drop-down values. Now, I would like to set the user-selected values as properties for the particular shape. How do I do it ?

In Format.js, I could add the custom attribute within the shape's style like below :

```
ss = this.format.getSelectionState();
ss.style.myProperty = 'my property value';
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. It's EditorUi.js Following code snippet in 'styleChanged' listener helped :

```
var value = graph.getModel().getValue(cells[0]);
var doc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
var obj = doc.createElement('object');
var key = evt.getProperty('keys');
var value = evt.getProperty('values');
obj.setAttribute(key, value || '');
cells[0].value = obj;
```